An isomorphism involving tensor products and Hom.
Let $R^{''}$ be a $R$-algebra. We need to show that $Hom_{R}(M, Hom_{R^{''}}(K, M^{''})) \cong Hom_{R^{''}}(M \underset{R}{\otimes} K, M^{''})$. I observe the following, given a map $\phi$ in LHS, this map induces a map the map $(x,y) \mapsto \phi(x)(y)$ from $M \times N \to M^{''}$, which we check to be $R$-bilinear. By the universal property of tensor products, this map then induces a unique homomorphism $M \underset{R}{\otimes} N \to M^{''}$ such that $x \otimes y \mapsto \phi(x)(y)$. Question 1: How to show this homomorphism is $R^{''}$-linear.
Again let $\psi$ be map in the RHS. By definition $\psi$ is a $R^{''}$-linear homomorphism from $M \underset{R}{\otimes} N \to M^{''}$. For $m \in M$ define a map $m \mapsto \psi(m, \_)$. Note that $\psi(m, \_): K \to M^{''}$ defined by $\psi(m,k) = \psi(m \otimes k)$. Question 2: Is $\psi(m, \_)$ a $R^{''}$-linear map? And why? Question 3: Why is the map $m \mapsto \psi(m,\_)$ a $R-$linear homomorphism? Question 4: Is this correspondence a bijective correspondence? And is it a isomorphism?

Fix your title.

Can you suggest one?

It's a MathJax error, and I can't read it, so no, I can't fix it.

Duplicate question.
